# adding category and tags to admin plugins menu

Tags: codex

How to create a tag and category for plugins just like the function shown below performs for pages?

```
function add_categories_to_pages() {
   register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_categories_to_pages' );

function add_tags_to_pages() {
   register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'page' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_tags_to_pages');
```

I tried to manipulate for category but with no success

Comment: I tried your code. It works. The category and tag is under pages menu. What is your difficulty? You see any error message? Or not effect? I just added to theme functions.php to test.

Comment: I didn't ask the right question. now I edited the question hope it is more clearly

Comment: Your question is not clear! You want to categories the *plugins* !!! Do you mean the WP plugins? I'm not sure what you are actually trying to do. You better clarify your intention a bit more! @James

Comment: @James do you want to add the category and tags in your custom plugins or do you want to add the code inside your plugin code? It sounds confusing.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenient, I want to be able to manage my installed plugins with tags and category-screenshot-https://snipboard.io/bQy5L8.jpg

Comment: plugin is not a post type, you cannot do that, you need to write custom solutions if you want to create tag and category functions for plugins.